# Type check in Swift

Tags: swift

I am not able to do the following type check that I thought should work:

```
var str:String?

//Compiler error: Downcast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optional; did you mean to use '!'?
if str is String {

}

//Compiler error: is test is always true
if str! is String {
    println("str is optional string")
}
```

Comment: I want to illustrate the use of is type check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From ["Type-Casting Operators"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html) in the Swift documentation 
(emphasis mine):

> The is operator checks at runtime whether the expression can be
>   downcast to the specified type. It returns true if the expression can
>   be downcast to the specified type; otherwise, it returns false.
>   If casting to the specified type is **guaranteed to succeed or fail**, a
>   compile-time error is raised.

`String` is not a proper subclass of `String?` or `String`, therefore the `is`
operator cannot be used here. And to check if `str` has a value one would use
an optional assigment instead: `if let theString = str { ... }`.

Working examples:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

func foo(a : A) {
    if a is B {
        // a is an instance of the B subclass
    }
}

func bar(obj: AnyObject) {
    if obj is NSNull {
        // The Null object
    }
}
```

In many cases the conditional cast `as?` is more useful because it returns an
a value of the specified type:

```
func foo(a : A) {
    if let b = a as? B {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of using "is" check is it see if it can be downcasted.  If String cannot be downcasted to String?, then it should return false, no? Otherwise how do we check a type?

Comment: @Boon: String cannot be downcasted to String?. Casting String to String? is *guaranteed to fail*, therefore the compiler error (as specified in the documentation cited above). - For `var str:AnyObject?` you could test `if str is String ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` is a `String?` which is an *optional*; an *optional* can never be a `String` as it is a wholly distinct type.  Thus `if str is String` can *never* be true and the compiler tells you about it.

Similarly `str!` unwraps `Sting?` and the result is *always* `String`.  Thus `if str! is String` is always true.

The use of `is` is illustrated with:

```
class Shape {}
class Rectangle : Shape {}
class Circle : Shape {}

func draw (s:Shape) {
  if s is Rectangle {}
  else if s is Circle {}
  else {}
}
```

In the `draw` function, the compiler recognizes that `Rectangle` and `Circle` are subtypes of the arguments `Shape` type and therefore the `if` statements are allowed.